# jquery, ajax and CKEditor - how to "unbind" a CKEditor instance

Tags: jquery, ajax, ckeditor

Hey, I'm using jquery, ajax and CKEditor:

```
$( '.ckeditor' ).ckeditor();
```

The first time the page is loaded through ajax the `ckeditor()` is fired off without a hitch.  The second time it fails.  Normally when binding you do something like:

```
.unbind('click').bind('click',function{...})
```

What do I do to unbind `ckeditor()`?

Answer (score 5):

Best I've found is ...

```
if (CKEDITOR.instances['ckeditor']) {
    CKEDITOR.remove(CKEDITOR.instances['ckeditor']);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get a CKEDITOR object reference by using:

```
var editor = $('.ckeditor').ckeditorGet();
```

and then you can destory it like this:

```
CKEDITOR.remove(editor);
```

Comment: But if no instance currently exists it causes an error.  Can I check for valid instances before calling ckeditorGet()?

Comment: The easiest way around this is to wrap this call in a try-catch block.

Comment: But if you want to dive deeper into to it you can look at the CKEDITOR.instances collection and see if your editor is defined there.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work for my purposes.  Moved to TinyMCE which seems to work well.  Thanks anyways.

Comment: Frankly I dislike both... Trying to move out of rich-text editors these days and move to alternative markup solutions (wikiformat, markdown, etc.) still looking for the perfect syntax and client/server tools.

Comment: btw: just for my knowledge and the completeness of this page here. Did my solution didn't work for you or it was something else?

Comment: I tried using a try..catch block but for some reason ckeditorGet never found anything and, as before, went to try to add another ckeditor instance which interfered with the first.  Def appreciate the try though.

Answer (score 2):

I did it long way :). You may count the amount of CK instances this way:

```
function countProps(obj) {
    var l = 0;
    for (p in obj) l++;
    return l;
}
if ( countProps(CKEDITOR.instances) ) { 
// to assure you have at least one instance of ckeditor
// you may want to use more complicated checks - in my case I have only one editor 
// instance per page
    editor = $('youreditor').ckeditorGet();
    CKEDITOR.remove(editor); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way
Get instances by name , If exist then remove:

```
  var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['name'];
  if (editor) {
      editor.destroy(true);
  }
```

OR

```
  var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['name'];
  if (editor) {
      CKEDITOR.remove(editor);
  }
```